# How to Add and Subtract numbers using SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, ontology

Is there any function to sum and subtract two numbers (integer or long data types) from two different classes using SPARQL?  how to use it ?

Comment: ehm, what about `+` and `-`? and either use it in a `BIND` or place where you select the projection variables

Comment: @AKSW thank u so much

Answer (score 6):

As AKSW is suggesting on the comment here it is an example query that adds two variables and projects the result in the total variable.

```
SELECT  ?total
{  ?x ns:itemcount ?xcount .
   ?y ns:itemcount ?ycount.
   BIND (?xcount + ?ycount AS ?total) 
}
```

See [SPARQL 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#bind) for futher details

Comment: Don't you mean `+` instead of `*`?

Comment: Yes, the example in SPARQL documentation got me confused. I'll update the answer, thank you.

Comment: @Cristiano Thank u so much for the illustration